# T-SQL query to return the number of users assigned to the role with the RoleName ‘Administrators’

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with the problem in the title. I have tried lots of different things to get this query to work but I cannot get it quite right. This is one of my attempts:

```
SELECT r.RoleName, COUNT(u.UserID) AS NumberOfUsers 
FROM Roles r INNER JOIN UserRoles u ON u.UserRoleID = r.RoleID
WHERE r.RoleName ='Administators'
GROUP BY r.RoleName;
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output..? coz seems like your query is correct.

Comment: Im supposed to produce only 1 row with the name of the role and how many users are assigned to it.

Comment: Seems your try is correct.Then what answer you got now with this query?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the ID where you try to match the tables on?

```
SELECT r.RoleName, COUNT(u.UserID) AS NumberOfUsers 
FROM Roles r 
INNER JOIN UserRoles u 
ON r.RoleID = u.RoleID
WHERE r.RoleName ='Administators'
GROUP BY r.RoleName;
```

If this does not work, what output do you get when running this query?